# Is there a way to install SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) on Ubuntu?

Tags: mssql

Well, I don't know if it is a valid question or not but, I need to install three SQL Server services on my laptop namely: Analysis services, Integration services, and Reporting services. [Windows installer offers an option to install these services through SSDT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMgxc.png)

Still after a lot of searching, I couldn't find any solution. I have already installed SQL Server 2017 on my Ubuntu machine, but now I need your help for installing these services :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. These are Windows tools to be used on a Windows machine.

From [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-develop-overview?view=sql-server-linux-2017#use-existing-sql-tools-on-windows-with-sql-server-on-linux):

> **Use existing SQL tools on Windows with SQL Server on Linux**
>
> Tools that currently run on Windows such as SSMS, SSDT, and PowerShell, also work with SQL Server 2017 on Linux. Although they do not run natively on Linux, you can still manage remote SQL Server instances on Linux.
>
> See the following topics for more information:
>
> - [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-develop-use-ssms?view=sql-server-linux-2017)
> - [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-develop-use-ssdt?view=sql-server-linux-2017)
> - [SQL PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-manage-powershell?view=sql-server-linux-2017)

so ...

> Still after a lot of searching, I couldn't find any solution. I have already installed SQL Server 2017 on my Ubuntu machine, but now I need your help for installing these services :)

You need a Windows machine; if that was not the case you would be able to use their tools without any connection to Microsoft.

Possible method: install virtualbox in your Ubuntu desktop, Windows in there and the tools in there and then connect to your SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

I tried to install SSDT on my Windows machine in the first place but I was getting an error 0x800703F3.
The error was occuring because I had the latest version 15.7.1 of Visual Studio, and SSDT was only supported up to version 15.6.7. It was not possible to roll-back to previous versions unless I perform a total new installation.

That's why I was trying to install the required services on my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article[1] that describes it with docker...  Specifically it downloads a linux version of the tools[2] to extract into the container... should work with Ubuntu directly.

```
wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip \
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=873926 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage \
    && rm sqlpackage.zip
```

1. https://www.wintellect.com/devops-sql-server-dacpac-docker/
2. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=873926

Answer (score 0):

I installed yesterday Visual Studio Code for linux on Ubuntu 18.10 after having installed SQL Server 2017.
It looks very interesting as support a lot of different languages.
By the way, I'm trying to connect with the DB, still without success!

https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Comment: Connecting to an SQL Server Database using VS Code in Ubuntu is quite simple. You just need to do a few steps: First of all, make sure the database engine is running. Then, download the SQL extension from marketplace and then simply connect with your database by entering the credentials of your database user (which you usually create while installing the database). I hope this will help you getting started :)